# How do I resolve this argument error for RenderTarget2D?

Tags: arguments, xna-4.0, rendertarget

I'm working with a bit of XNA code, as a beginner. So i use this tutorial, but it appears that i am doing something and i do not know why.

http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/theroadnottaken/theroadnottaken.shtml

I am at the part with Path collision, and this is how my code is written!

```
mTrackRender = new RenderTarget2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, mCarWidth + 100,
               mCarHeight + 100, 1, SurfaceFormat.Color,DepthFormat.Depth24);

mTrackRenderRotated = new RenderTarget2D(graphics.GraphicsDevice, mCarWidth + 100,
                   mCarHeight + 100, 1);
```

I have declared mTrackREnder, and mTrackREnderRotated has objects at class level.

Well, what the issue ism i get this error for both of them:

> Error 3   'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.RenderTarget2D' does not
>   contain a constructor that takes 4 arguments'

What am i doing wrong? How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: You may have more luck with finding an answer for this question over at http://www.gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [constructors of the RenderTarget2D class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.rendertarget2d.rendertarget2d%28v=xnagamestudio.40%29.aspx). None of them take the arguments that you are trying to pass.

In the first case, you are passing an integer where the constructor expects a boolean. Integers are not implicitely convertible to booleans in C#; use `true` and `false` instead of 1 and 0.

In the second case, it's not clear which constructor you are trying to call, but none of them take 4 arguments and none of them take an integer as the 4th argument.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my problem!
And thanks for showing me the Overload table, it will come in handy!